# Else statement in Python not working properly

Tags: python

Was wondering if anyone could help me fix the last else statement with the error message. It works if I type in anything else that's not YyNn, however, the error message still does show up if I type in YyNn. I've been at it all night, and I feel like I'm missing the obvious answer - but it's been driving me crazy. Would appreciate an solution for this. Thanks very much.

```
import random
score = 0

def rollAllDice():
   values=random.randint(1,6), random.randint(1,6), random.randint(1,6), random.randint(1,6), random.randint(1,6)
   print("You rolled 5 dice. The values are:")
   print("Die 1:", values[0]) 
   print("Die 2:", values[1]) 
   print("Die 3:", values[2]) 
   print("Die 4:", values[3]) 
   print("Die 5:", values[4])
   return values
myDice=rollAllDice()

def allSame(myDice):
    result = myDice[0] == myDice[1] and myDice[0] == myDice[2] and myDice[0] == myDice[3] and myDice[0] == myDice[4]
    len(set(myDice)) == 1
    return result

def diceReroll(myDice):
   if allSame(myDice):
      if keepDie1[0] in 'YyNn':
         die1 = random.randint(1,6)
      elif keepDie2[1] in 'YyNn':
         die2 = random.randint(1,6)
      elif keepDie3[2] in 'YyNn':
         die3 = random.randint(1,6)
      elif keepDie4[3] in 'YyNn':
         die4 = random.randint(1,6)
      elif keepDie5[4] in 'YyNn':
         die5 = random.randint(1,6)
   else: # < ---- the else statement I need help on.
      print("I'm sorry. Please only enter Y or N.")

keepDie1=input("\nWould you like to reroll die 1? [Y/N]: ")
keepDie2=input("Would you like to reroll die 2? [Y/N]: ")
keepDie3=input("Would you like to reroll die 3? [Y/N]: ")
keepDie4=input("Would you like to reroll die 4? [Y/N]: ")
keepDie5=input("Would you like to reroll die 5? [Y/N]: ")
diceReroll(myDice)
```

Comment: An unrelated note: you can make the ifelse block look cleaner by converting user's input to lowercase and leaving only 2 possible inputs instead of 4: `if allSame(myDice.lower()):
      if keepDie1[0] in 'yn':`

Comment: Your `else` is at the same indentation level as `if allSame(mydice):` line. The error message is printed if not all results are the same, regardless of what user input is.

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas thanks i appreciate it but i got an attribute error saying ```'tuple object has no attritube to 'lower'```?

Comment: Your code doesn't make a difference between yes and no. Also the `else` seems to be related to an `if` with a completely different meaning.

Comment: @Selcuk, what can I do to fix that? I tried putting the ```else``` on the same indentation level as the if/elif in ```keepDie``` but it doesn't show up.

Comment: @KlausD. I see, how can I make the difference? What can I do to fix the ```else```?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I took the liberty to make a few assumptions about your code. If you
>   think I went too far, let me know in the comments and I will refractor
>   the answer according to your needs.

The base issue with the if/else loop is indentation (as already mentioned by others in the comments). But I think the real reason why you have this issue lies with the structure of your code. Thus I would suggest you make two changes that would isolate the user input and remove the problematic if/else clause.

First, you are validating the input in your dice rolling logic, hence having your if/else loop:

```
if allSame(myDice):
      if keepDie1[0] in 'YyNn':
         die1 = random.randint(1,6)
      elif keepDie2[1] in 'YyNn':
         die2 = random.randint(1,6)
      elif keepDie3[2] in 'YyNn':
         die3 = random.randint(1,6)
      elif keepDie4[3] in 'YyNn':
         die4 = random.randint(1,6)
      elif keepDie5[4] in 'YyNn':
         die5 = random.randint(1,6)
   else: # < ---- the else statement I need help on.
      print("I'm sorry. Please only enter Y or N.")
```

The else part here, as @Selcuk has noted is badly indented, resulting in you getting that error message. **This function already contains your application logic and it should not be dealing with user input validation at all.**

I would suggest you rewrite the user input part as a separate function (the change to the user prompt message is called an f-string. You can look it up in case you don't understand it):

```
def diceRerollPrompt(diceNumber):
    while True:
        prompt = input(f'Would you like to reroll die {diceNumber}? [Y/N]: ').upper()
        if prompt in 'YN':
            return prompt
        else:
            print("I'm sorry. Please only enter Y or N.")

keepDie1=diceRerollPrompt(1)
keepDie2=diceRerollPrompt(2)
keepDie3=diceRerollPrompt(3)
keepDie4=diceRerollPrompt(4)
keepDie5=diceRerollPrompt(5)
```

> This piece of code would repeatedly ask the user to input characters
>   until our user enters yYn or N. It ensures that if the user makes a
>   mistake, the user is immediately telegraphed that his/her input is wrong. You also
>   isolate your code from bad input very early on and not need to write
>   heavy validation in the business logic greatly simplifying your `allSame()` function. Win-win for you and the user.

Afterwards, you can simply delete the problematic if/else loop at all and change your `diceReroll` function like this:

```
def diceReroll(myDice):
   if allSame(myDice):
      if keepDie is 'Y':
         die1 = random.randint(1,6)
      elif keepDie2 is 'Y':
         die2 = random.randint(1,6)
      elif keepDie3 is 'Y':
         die3 = random.randint(1,6)
      elif keepDie4 is 'Y':
         die4 = random.randint(1,6)
      elif keepDie5 is 'Y':
         die5 = random.randint(1,6)
```

> Note that I took the liberty to change the `YyNn` to just `Y` as you
>   would not want to reroll the dice if the user said NO, right?

**Full solution below**

```
import random
score = 0

def rollAllDice():
   values=random.randint(1,6), random.randint(1,6), random.randint(1,6), random.randint(1,6), random.randint(1,6)
   print("You rolled 5 dice. The values are:")
   print("Die 1:", values[0]) 
   print("Die 2:", values[1]) 
   print("Die 3:", values[2]) 
   print("Die 4:", values[3]) 
   print("Die 5:", values[4])
   return values
myDice=rollAllDice()

def allSame(myDice):
    result = myDice[0] == myDice[1] and myDice[0] == myDice[2] and myDice[0] == myDice[3] and myDice[0] == myDice[4]
    len(set(myDice)) == 1
    return result

def diceReroll(myDice):
   if allSame(myDice):
      if keepDie1 is 'Y':
         die1 = random.randint(1,6)
      elif keepDie2 is 'Y':
         die2 = random.randint(1,6)
      elif keepDie3 is 'Y':
         die3 = random.randint(1,6)
      elif keepDie4 is 'Y':
         die4 = random.randint(1,6)
      elif keepDie5 is 'Y':
         die5 = random.randint(1,6)

def diceRerollPrompt(diceNumber):
    while True:
        # if you want to use the simple string concatenation:
        # prompt = input('Would you like to reroll die ' + diceNumber +'? [Y/N]: ').upper()
        prompt = input(f'Would you like to reroll die {diceNumber}? [Y/N]: ').upper()
        if prompt in 'YN':
            return prompt
        else:
            print("I'm sorry. Please only enter Y or N.")

keepDie1=diceRerollPrompt(1)
keepDie2=diceRerollPrompt(2)
keepDie3=diceRerollPrompt(3)
keepDie4=diceRerollPrompt(4)
keepDie5=diceRerollPrompt(5)
diceReroll(myDice)

'''
```

Comment: Hey dude, this is super detailed and so helpful. Thank you very much. I am wondering if there's anything else as a replacement for the ```f-string``` prompt, as we haven't been taught it in class yet. And as you changing the ```YyNn``` to just ```Y```, does it still exclude the values if you put in N? The only reason why I want ```N``` is so it excludes the values if you put in N as shown in the first 5 dice statement, so if it works like that, then that's awesome.

Comment: f-string is just a fancier way of saying `input('Would you like to reroll die ' + diceNumber + '? [Y/N]: ').upper()` Both ways are interchangeable. I will add it to the full solution

Comment: as for dice reroll, notice that I used `input(...).upper(). This means that if the user enters anything yYnN, the final input in the code will only be one of the 'YN' (it will be capitalized). Finally, in the diceReroll() it would only reroll the die if the corresponding keepDieX input was Y

Answer (score 2):

Excellent response by @Simas.

I would just like point out that you will never be able to re-roll anything unless all 5 dice are the same. The reason is that in `allSame` you are using the logical `and` operator. By definition, all conditions must be true in order for it to return true. Therefore, if you get even 1 false, it returns false. So in `diceReroll`, the first `if` condition is always going to evaluate to `false`. And maybe this is what you want, however you shouldn't be asking if the user wants to re-roll anything if that's the case. By changing the `and`s to `or`s you then get the behavior that the dice re-roll will only work if the first dice is equal to at least one other die. (Not sure what the `len(set(mydice)) == 1` is for...it seems to be a boolean statement but isn't connected to the previous statement by an `and` or `or`)

And with the current `if-elif` structure, only the first dice to have a 'Y' will be re-rolled because after it evaluates it, it ignores the rest. So, this may be better suited as a series of `if` statements. Also, all the `keepDie`x needs to have 0 in the brackets, otherwise you get an index out of bounds.

```
def diceReroll(myDice):
    if allSame(myDice):
        if keepDie1[0] is 'Y':
            die1 = random.randint(1, 6)
            print(die1)
        if keepDie2[0] is 'Y':
            die2 = random.randint(1, 6)
            print(die2)
       if keepDie3[0]is 'Y':
            die3 = random.randint(1, 6)
            print(die3)
       if keepDie4[0] is 'Y':
            die4 = random.randint(1, 6)
            print(die4)
       if keepDie5[0] is 'Y':
            die5 = random.randint(1, 6)
            print(die5)
```

Comment: Thanks for the shoutout. You are also entirely correct here. I chose to not comment on this part as I have already changed and assumed a lot about OP's task. I was afraid that I'd go too off-topic if I redefined more than I already did~

Comment: Makes sense, considering that it wasn't technically a part of his question. But it did cause me a little confusion as I was trying to figure out what his code was doing.

Comment: yes, definitely a useful input. Took me a while to figure it at the time as well~~